# Avoid object multiple inheritance

Tags: php, oop

I'm creating a form generator and i'm actually working on an specific element : `DuplicableElement`.

The form can contains a special container (`DuplicableContainer`) that used jQuery plugin ([sheepit](http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/)) to duplicate itself.

To get working this, the `DuplicatableContainer` can only have `DuplicableElement` in its child because they are a lot of things specific to them.

The problem is that php does not allow **multiple inheritance**. (should works with php "Traits" but not supported actually). I can't make a `DuplicableTextBox` extends simultaneously `DuplicableFormElement` and the normal `TextBox` element.

I hope i was enough clear.

Edit: Even with "Traits", the problem still exists, and i can't find a clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also inject behaviors/plugins into your elements providing the functionality of traits but without official support.

```
<?php
class Car {
  public $behaviors = array();

  public function __call($method, $params) {
    foreach($this->behaviors as $behavior) {
      if (method_exists($behavior, $method)) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($behavior, $method), $params);
      }
    }
  }
}

class Engine {
  public function start() { echo 'Started'; }
}

$car = new Car;
$engine = new Engine;
$car->behaviors[] = $engine;
$car->start(); // Started
```

Comment: +1 Nice technique. Is it some kind of transparent wrapper or it has some official name?

Comment: Look as the only solution isn't it ? Thanks

Comment: This is next to your idea : [link](http://labs.contexttheory.com/Blog/tabid/94/EntryId/12/Simulating-Multiple-Inheritance-in-PHP-5-Just-a-bit-of-noodling-about.aspx)

Comment: In fact this seems good but not really : If you call one object method from an Inheritance class instance, and this method call another method, it will always call the method of the same object even if it was redifine in an other that is prior.

Comment: @Leto So will traits. Many aspects of OOP *hide* some functionality or execution in one way or another. This is one of the many criticisms of OO - not traits or my particular solution. Tools like a good debugger will guide you through the inheritance hierarchy and magic-method execution.

Comment: Additionally, multiple-inheritance is commonly considered to give off a decent [code-smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) as pointed out by some of the other answers to your question.

Comment: Ok, so what can i do ? (not sure to have correctly understood you) Use traits ? I'm guessing they also give (purist) problems : Trait i'm mading use property in its methods that the class that use it must have. So it would be great if trait could be declare saying "only this class and its children could use the trait" (to have the properties defined in it)

Answer (score 1):

Do the `DuplicableElement`s specifically need to be a class? If the public interface to the object is what matters, you could make `DuplicableElement` an interface instead. A class can extend one class and implement multiple interfaces all at once.

Comment: Already think about that but it needs a class to declare implemented method in it.